# C#: Http Get behavior varies in different LAN

Tags: c#, http

I started an HTTP server in a local area network from C# as:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
listener.Start();
```

In another thread, it sends response as:

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream)) {
    writer.WriteLine(responseJson);
}
```

And in my client code, Http request is sent and processed as:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This server-client application works well in one LAN. But after I copied the application to another machine in another LAN, the last line of client code (await response result) got error " The input was not in a correct format". I really have no idea what it is about. I visited the server url from web browser, the correct response could be retrieved. So this is more likely to be a client-side issue, I guess.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: You're going from the client to a server outside of the client LAN?

Comment: @rene each time they are in the same LAN.

Comment: I can only imagine the browser uses a webproxy and your client app doesn't but I'm not 100% sure if that makes sense if you're in the same LAN but maybe I should ask if both client and server are in the same subnet. Can you share what the IP address looks like  of your client and the server and their subnet mask.

Comment: In LAN 1, IP addresses are like 192.168.3.*, subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. In LAN 2, IP addresses are all 192.168.0.* and the subnet mask is also 255.255.255.0. I really have no idea at all now

Comment: `HttpClient` will automatically detect and use network proxies. You may need to turn that off.